# Find similar data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, similarity

I have table with weather statistics eg:

```
----------------------
| day | temp | falls |
|-----|------|-------|
|  1  |  12  |   30  |
|  2  |  18  |    0  |
|  3  |  13  |   10  |
----------------------
```

and I want to find day, which is most similar:

```
Today: 14°C, 0mm falls
Most similar day: 3
```

Is this possible to achieve it in MySQL only?

Comment: Please define `similar`..

Comment: Very interesting. Any attempts so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check absolute differences between both factors, add them, and search for the lowest sum possible.

**But You need to define `similar` more precisely.**

Let's say temperature is twice more important than falls, you'll give a factor 2 to `temp`, and a factor 1 to `falls`. Then use this kind of query :

```
SELECT day 
FROM weather 
ORDER BY (
    2 * ABS(temp - 14) 
  + 1 * ABS(falls - 0)
) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I really didn't think about factor, it's really good improvement and it works like a charm. Thank you zessx and Paul Draper

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that this query does not select day 3.

Comment: The goal was to explain how to use factors in this situation. Settings these factors return to @Tomasz

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming "similar" refers to similar temperature and similar falls.

```
 SELECT day FROM weather ORDER BY ABS(temp - 14) + .2 * ABS(falls - 0) LIMIT 1
```

Though `ABS(temp - 14) + .2 * ABS(falls - 0)` can be adjusted. Hear, the difference in falls (mm) is weighted less than the difference in temp (C).

For example, if we instead used `ABS(temp - 14) + ABS(falls - 0)`, day two would be chosen.